# Difference between MariaDB and MySQL when handling illegal dates

Tags: mysql, mariadb

`SELECT now() < now() + 40` is accepted in `MySQL` and not in `MariaDB` . In `MySQL` the addition is seen as if it were days.

```
SELECT DATE(now()) < now() + 40, DATE(now()) + 40
MariaDB : 0, 20150667
MySQL   : 1, 20150667
```

I know I should use `INTERVAL` but this is legacy code and changing it is unlikely. Any suggestions? Is this 'works as designed'?

Comment: What exactly does “is not accepted” mean here? // How MySQL handles any “non-standard” stuff a lot of times comes down to configuration settings, SQL modes, etc. I suggest you go and compare those between your MySQL and MariaDB setup (as far as applicable).

Comment: The config is exactly equal. Just a drop-in replacement of `MySQL` with `MariaDB`. `my.cfg` did not change. 'accepted' means that MySQL does not throw a warning but MariaDB does. As reported by Hibernate from a JPA application. And MySQL handles the illegal date as if the date is just a date in the next month (looks like it at least).

Comment: What’s the warning message?

Comment: Hmmm, also in `MySQL` the query is just plain wrong as seen by `select '2015-07-05' < 20150631` showing 1 in `MySQL`. I think the queries have to be changed after all...

Comment: The warning is: `SQL Warning Code: 1292, SQLState: HY000, Incorrect datetime value: '20150634'`

Comment: What’s your MariaDB version? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/#incompatibilities-between-mariadb-53-and-mysql-51-and-mariadb-52 says, _“MariaDB [5.3] performs stricter checking of date, datetime and timestamp values.”_ You could try and see what you get with the [`ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` flag](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/date-and-time-literals/#date-and-time-literals-and-the-sql_mode) set (but I am not sure if that will still get you the results you want.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I concluded that the query is wrong. Even in MySQL it does not give the expected results and so we have to change it. No choice. MariaDB version is 10.0.19.

Comment: As long as the total daynumber stays valid the unit can be seen as day. This is because the date is converted to long and then the int is added to that. So 2015-06-20 becomes 20150620. Adding 5 then becomes 20150625 what is a valid date. Obviously this only works as long as the day stays within the same month.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add